# Gradle IDE support

Tags: gradle, groovy, ide

Am trying to dive in with gradle's tasks and gradle as a build system .

For example i have this following task

```java
task copyDocs(type: Copy) {
    from 'gradle/1.txt'
    into '.'
    doLast {
        println 'THIS IS QUITE LEVEL' }
}
tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("copyDocs") }
```

But when i try with my Spring tools suite for eclipse , there is no auto complete nor suggested with `Ctrl+space` .

I've tried to install , gradle IDE pack and groovy development tools with eclipse marketplace , Still cant get auto complete nor suggested .

for example , the `doLast` and `finalizedBy` , i had no idea of their existing, once i seen once , googled about , and now i use them .

Is there a way to auto complete or show suggestion ?

if not , Any idea where i can read about tasks and available operation , beside the official docs which is my only source for now.

Comment: I'm not sure of the state of Eclipse support, but if you switch to using the Kotlin scripting instead of Groovy, and use IntelliJ Idea, it works great

Comment: Yeah , thats the only possible support that i know of, i ve even seen a question about kotlin support that intelliJ Idea will support that , if i cant find for groocy am definitely switching , Thanks .

Comment: As mentioned, the Kotlin DSL will provide you a more robust intellisense, especially in IntelliJ. However, the Groovy DSL can work as well, but you have structure your build logic in a way your IDE can understand it. Even IntelliJ does not understand the Groovy DSL entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives an idea on how to extend the editor to support type inferencing and code completion for your gradle script in Spring Tool Suite (aka Eclipse IDE).  It is discussed further here: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1125

Pre-requisites:

1. import Gradle API jar(s)
2. install Groovy Development Tools
3. add `~/.groovy/greclipse/global_dsld_support`

Create `Gradle.dsld` file in the dsld support directory with the following contents:

```
def isBuildScript = fileExtension('gradle') & (~fileName('settings.gradle'))

contribute(isBuildScript & isThisType()) {
  delegatesTo 'org.gradle.api.Project'
}

contribute(isBuildScript & isThisType() & enclosingCallName('task') & inClosure()) {
  delegatesTo 'org.gradle.api.Task'
}
```

Right-click on you `build.gradle` file and choose *Open With > Groovy Editor*.  With a descriptor like this, you will get:

[image: Gradle DSLD code completion]

As you can see, it is by no means complete.  But you can add to the DSLD and over time you can get quite a bit of assistance from the editor.  If you share via the issue ticket (from above), the community can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot , This is definitely helpful for my progress , Thanks again .